# Parallel std::lists, removing items in list A based on state of items in list B?

Tags: c++, stdlist

How would I accomplish the following?

> List A is a series of `Foo`s, list B is a series of `double`s representing time remaining until the `Foo` at the `i`th position of List A is removed. That is, if a double in List B is less than zero, the `Foo` at the same position in List A as the less than zero double in List B is removed from List A and then the less-than-zero double is removed from List B.

```
List A:
A B C D E

List B (in seconds):
1.0 0.33 0.0 5.0 0.01

//1 tick of 0.33 seconds

List B:
0.67 0.0 -0.33 4.67 -0.32

//Remove offending List A elements based on state of List B
List A:
A B D

//Remove invalid List B elements
List B:
0.67 0.0 4.67
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of `std::remove_if` for List B, but how would I remove the items for List A if I do that? Sadly, iterators of different lists aren't compatible and, except using manual implementations, there is no way to iterate through a list AND know the index of each value.

Comment: Refactor and use a single `std::list<std::pair<Foo, double>>`? (if that's possible of course) Maintaining synchronized data structures like your two lists is usually a headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider using a list of structures instead of two lists. Then you can use remove_if and other list functions.